# Limit data while joining

Tags: sql

I have two tables. "A" and "B". I have join these tables, but I want to eliminate some columns from the table "B". How can I do that?

Comment: You select the columns that you want. It is that simple.

Comment: do you mean columns are rows?

Comment: I'm guessing you're using `SELECT *`. The answer is to not do that - there's no syntax to select all columns _except_ an explicit list.

Comment: @DStanley I wish SQL implemented that. I've needed it so many times.

Comment: Well... show the columns of each table so we can help you.

Answer (score 0):

You could do a Left Join and in the select, choose the columns you need. A handy way of visualizing joins is to think of them like venn diagrams:

[image]